# Multiple flexsliders not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, flexslider

In my rails app I have one Flexslider on the home page and then one on an about page in which I want to have customized differently than the one on the homepage. Right now the one on the about page behaves exactly like the one on the home page. I followed the directions on flexsliders [info page](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) but still can't seem to get it working properly.

ERB:

```
<div id="collection-slider" class="flexslider"> 
  <ul class="slides">
    <% if @collection_images.present? %>
      <% @collection_images.each do |image| %>
        <li>
            <%= image_tag(image.image(:large), rel: @collection.name) %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

jQuery

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide"
});

$('#collection-slider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide"
  directionNav: true,
});
```